# I'm learning bash and had confusion understanding how redirection operators work (the order of evaluation)

Tags: bash

I was going through the bash reference manual and the below commands does
'ls > dirlist 2>&1' - the command directs both output and std err to the file dirlis (from the bash reference manual).

In the above command, the last part of the expression '2>&1', why is no pipe or redirection operator needed before '2>&1'? i.e. 'ls > dirlist < 2>&1'

2>&1 - is redirect std err to std out, ls > dirlist mean (redirect output of ls to dirlist). how does the 2>&1 affect ls > dirlist(since this should already be completed left to right command execution)?

Answer (score 0):

> In the above command, the last part of the expression '2>&1', why is
> no pipe or redirection operator needed before '2>&1'? i.e. 'ls >
> dirlist < 2>&1'

No, pipe is not required. Entire operation is executed within the same process. What is being done here is the short hand for the command `ls 1> dirlist 2> dirlist`.
&1 implies refer to the file where output is sent. The same command can be executed as well as `ls 2> dirlist 1>&2`.
Refer [link](https://www.brianstorti.com/understanding-shell-script-idiom-redirect/). First search result for 2>&1 has a decent explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe these are the key points into this [Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) introduction of the bash manual:

> Before a command is executed, its input and output may be redirected

So the shell handles the redirections before the command execution. This is the reason why this command

```sh
cat file > file
```

will result to an empty file. Because before the execution of `cat`, the shell will redirect the command's standard output to that `file`, will initialise it to an empty file, so the initial content of the file is lost.

> Redirections are processed in the order they appear, from left to
> right.

This is essential and should be combined with this:

> ls 2>&1 > dirlist
>
> directs only the standard output to file dirlist, because the standard
> error was made a copy of the standard output before the standard
> output was redirected to dirlist.

So the evaluation of the redirections happens from left to right, and it is important to see what is `2` and `1` when this happens, because the statement `2>&1` should not be interpreted as a "by reference assignment" but exactly `2` becomes a copy of `1`, of the instance of `1` at the moment of evaluation. Later, to the right, `1` is redirected to a file, but this has no effect for `2`.

This behaviour reminds the value assignment of a variable. `x=y` means that `x` gets the value of `y`. If later I do `y=z`,this has no effect to the value of `x`.

And in the different case:

```
ls > dirlist 2>&1
```

standard output first is redirected to a file. After that, the standard error (`2`) is redirected to standard output (`1`). At the moment of the last redirection, `1` was already redirected to a file, and `2` becomes a copy of `1`, so both are written to the file.

Comment: so 'ls 2>&1> dirlist' , in this scenario do we loose(not capturing) stderr? or stderr and stdoutput are both written to file?

Comment: Also 
'ls > dirlist 2>&1' - here first stdout is redirected to dirlist.
then 2 becomes a copy of 1/stderr was made copy of stdout  (i.e. 2 is now 'stdout') how can stderr be displayed in the stdout? since stderr contents should be replaced by stdout of ls?

Comment: `(a)` By default, stdout and stderr are going to the terminal. So here: `ls 2>&1> dirlist` , `2` became a copy of `1` when `1` was going to the terminal (not redirected to a file yet), so `2` goes to the terminal (yes, you don't capture it). `(b)` Nothing is "replaced", these are file descriptors, by default they go somewhere, and we can redirect them to go somewhere else. By default they both go to the terminal, nothing is "replaced" on the terminal.

Comment: what does it mean by 'became a copy' or 'was made a copy' in these contexts?

Comment: I have emphasized on that into the answer. I have an example comparison with the variable assignment "by value" or "by reference" to show the order of evaluation. Of course note that these are [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), not variables.

Comment: Think of the file descriptors as pointers, abstract entities, they just point somewhere and describe where a stream is going, and we can redirect that. They are not to be rewritten or replaced like variables.